# Unable to trigger hover on SVG object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to trigger my svg animation when I hover over `<span>`.
I had to use `<span>` over my object tag to enable my `<a>` to work but then I was not able to activate my :hover for my svg.

I've tried all ways to use JavaScript to trigger but am still unable to do it. 
Any idea if it is possible or not?

HTML:

```
<div class="links">  
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="facebook" class="facebook">
<span id="fbI"><object class="icon" id="faceb" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/fb.svg">  
<img src="images/fb.svg" alt="ssRight"/>
</object></span>
</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.links a
{
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1;
}

.links a span
{
     display: block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}

.links a object
{
    display: inline;
    position: relative; 
    z-index: -1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('span#fbI').hover(function(e) {
$('#faceb').trigger('mouseover');
})
```

OBJECT TAG SVG CODES:

```
<svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.45 79.45">
<defs>
<style>
  .cls-1 {
    fill: #878484;
  }

  .cls-2 {
    fill: #fff;
  }

    svg:hover #bg
    {
        fill: #205599;
    }


</style>
  </defs>
  <title>fb</title>
  <g>
    <circle id="bg" class="cls-1" cx="39.73" cy="39.73" r="39.73"/>
    <path id="fb" class="cls-2" d="M-897.51-    494c0,3.22,0,6.43,0,9.65a1,1,0,0,1-    1.2,1.19c-2.27-.05-4.54,0-    6.81,0a0.89,0.89,0,0,1-1.09-1.09c0-6.43,0-12.86,0-19.3,0-1.17,0-1.16-1.16-1.1-  0.85,0-1.7,0-2.55,0a0.58,0.58,0,0,1-.67-0.69c0-2,0-4,0-6.05a0.64,0.64,0,0,1,.8-0.75c0.88,0,1.77,0,2.65,0a0.76,0.76,0,0,0,1-.94,39.91,39.91,0,0,1,.11-5.85,7.72,7.72,0,0,1,7.65-7.07c2.3-.06,4.6-0.07,6.9-0.14a0.79,0.79,0,0,1,1,1c0,1.86,0,3.72,0,5.58a0.66,0.66,0,0,1-.81.81c-1,0-2.08,0-3.12,0-1.83,0-2.54.72-2.76,2.52-0.13,1.07,0,2.14-.08,3.21a0.66,0.66,0,0,0,.82.82c1.64,0,3.28,0,4.92,0,0.7,0,1,.18.87,0.92-0.23,2-.41,3.95-0.57,5.92a0.7,0.7,0,0,1-.83.76c-1.39,0-2.78,0-4.16,0-0.67,0-.94.11-0.91,0.86,0.06,1.64,0,3.28,0,4.92s0,3.22,0,4.82h0Z" transform="translate(940.65 544.4)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[the highlighted box is the span box, as u can see in my codes, once i display:block; it would cover over my object tag and thus being unable to trigger my hover over for it.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSD0P.png)

Comment: You are trying to trigger a mouseover event on `#faceb`, but your code doesn't show what happens on the mouseover.  To test, replace your second line with `$('faceb').css('background','red');` and see if anything happens.  That will tell you if the `.hover` event is being fired.

Comment: @Sablefoste I have tried what u said and yes the hover event is being fired. I am trying to trigger the mouseover state to be active, as my span is covering my object, when i mouse over, it can only read the span. But at the same time, I want my object tag hover to be activeas i have a hover animation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there your desired hover function can be achieved by the following.

```
$( "span#fbI" ).hover(function() {
  $('#fbI').css('background','purple')
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle for that. I dont know what effect u want so i just turned it purple.

https://jsfiddle.net/qansvs0n/4/

Comment: If however you are trying to start a animation on hover this can be done with css.

By using :hover of the svg element, change the animation-play-state to running

An example of this can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124550/animating-an-svg-on-hover

Comment: I've tried using animation play state to target the object before and it does not work. I'm trying to find a way to target the hover state of my object tag to activate my background color change inside the svg that is linked by the object tag.